# Is questions asking a product's End of Life on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897770/tomcat-7-end-of-life) asking Apache Tomcat 7.x End Of Life Date, on-topic? I flagged it as "off-topic" but it got aged away. I thought to ask in meta before I re-flag it.

Comment: [Here's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42996375/6214222)

Comment: Yes, with disturbing number of upvotes. :D. I recommend to close both of them.

Comment: I don't see why it would be off-topic.

Comment: @sevenseacat because it's essentially just a [support question for some product](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/6214222) with the answer being "Ask the people who make the software" / "go look at these resources"

Comment: @Keiwan doesn't seem any different to the 'use X method, as defined here (link) (details copied + pasted from link)' answers, which I see a lot of (and which are generally well received).

Comment: @sevenseacat well-received doesn't mean that the question/answer is always on-topic. and I have flagged copy-pasted/only link answers and those got removed as well. Also, I have seen a lot of old questions (historically significant with lots of upvotes) which are flagged as off-topic and closed/locked now.